# The Classic issue of entityManager.persist(): no errors but not inserting to db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persist

I am having a strange issue while inserting a new entry.

**Problem:** 
`entityManager.persist(myEntiy)` : line is executed but no entry is created in the db.

I know many had this issue before and i have read all of those posts but none of it answers my problem. I am not inserting an entry for the first time. So i have did the configuration and other basic things right. That means I do use `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager"/>` in my spring-core.xml and I do use an `@Transactional`on top of the methods in my dao.

**Solutions tried:** Adding `entityManager.flush()` after persist, but this resulted in

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in
>   progress.

**Also tried:**

`em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();`

which resulted in

> Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager

Then saw someone saying **the problem may be** the

> AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no
>   transaction in progress

but i didnt have anything in log saying that this may be the cause. And i dont have a clue what exactly is the solution if that is the issue. My hibernate log ends with the lines.

```html
DEBUG 0412185908 [80-exec-2 SqlStatementLogger.java: 104] select mySchema.sequence_for_my_entity_PK.nextval from dual
DEBUG 0412185908 [80-exec-2 SequenceGenerator.java: 127] Sequence identifier generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Long[20]]
DEBUG 0412185908 [80-exec-2 AbstractSaveEventListener.java: 131] Generated identifier: 20, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator
DEBUG 0412185908 [80-exec-2 LogicalConnectionImpl.java: 314] Releasing JDBC connection
DEBUG 0412185909 [80-exec-2 LogicalConnectionImpl.java: 332] Released JDBC connection
DEBUG 0412185909 [80-exec-2 ConnectionProxyHandler.java: 219] HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
```

no errors whatsoever there. Any help is appreciated.

My **spring-core.xml** have:

```html
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref= "jpaVendorAdapter"/>
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
<property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />    
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager"/>
<bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean> 
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
<property name="databasePlatform" value="${local.datasource.database.platform}" /> 
<property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
<property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean> 
<bean id="dataSource" class="${local.datasource.database.datasource}">
<property name="dataSourceName" value="${local.datasource.database.name}" />
<property name="URL" value="${local.datasource.database.url}" />
<property name="user" value="${local.datasource.database.user}" />
<property name="password" value="${local.datasource.database.password}" />
</bean>
```

And the **DaoImpl** is:

```html
@Repository
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {
 protected EntityManager entityManager;
 @Autowired
 AnotherDao anotherDao;
 public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
  return entityManager;
 }
 @PersistenceContext
 public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
  this.entityManager = entityManager;
 }
 @Override
 @Transactional
 public String saveNewInfo(Data dataObject, String scheduleType){
  String uniqueSessionId = null;
  History history = new History();
  SessionIdentifierGenerator sessionIdentifierGenerator = new SessionIdentifierGenerator();
  uniqueSessionId = sessionIdentifierGenerator.nextSessionId();
  Type type = anotherDao
     .getAppObject(dataObject.getApplication());
  history.setType(type.getType());
  history.setSessionId(uniqueSessionId);
  history.setSchedulerType(scheduleType);
  history.setStatusCode("1");
  history.setVersionNumber(dataObject.getVersionNumber());  
  entityManager.persist(history);
  return uniqueSessionId;
 }
}
```

Comment: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress. it should be an answer to you. So according to this, there can be some problems with configuration. @Transactional should work as a proxy, but it looks like it isn't in your situation. PostProcessor cannot read it for some reasons and that's why you haven't proxy. Define feasible PostProcessor for this annotation and debug it if it actually works

Comment: I dont understand why it is so even after using @transactional. This method  is no different than any other methods which i use to persist. Every other method works fine. Please point out if i am missing anything

Comment: is method called from outer transaction? Do any transactions occur before calling your method? Try to call this method from another transaction (it might be another method *which works*)

Comment: there is another transaction happening just before calling this method in my service. More like this

menuDao.saveNewMenu(); //working fine;

menuHistoryDao.updateHistory(); //persist not inserting;

Comment: have you tried to call updateHistory() (without calling the saveNewMenu)? I think you should identify your true problem by calling it from different "scopes". Saying scopes i mean to omit saveNewMenu and instead of this call your updateHistory. Also you can try to set propagation layer as "REQUIRED_NEW" in your updateHistory method

Comment: I tried calling the method alone. No changes. Tried REQUIRED_NEW too still same results.

Comment: Could you add the spring-context xml config (`transaction Manager`, `entityManger`, `.*Dao`) + snippets of the dao (wiring the entitymanager + save method)?

Comment: just to be sure, the method is public.. right ?

Comment: yes the method is public.

Comment: can you try enabling debug logs and see if you get any addtional info when persist method is called ?

Comment: Any chance `anotherDao.getAppObject(dataObject.getApplication())` is doing something (e.g. throwing but subsequently eating EmptyResultDataAccessException) that makes the transaction rollback?

Comment: My anotherDao is  working fine . i logged its value and checked. Still dont understand what it is that i am doing wrong.

Comment: debug logs doesnt gave anything new too

Comment: I dont understand how we can log and see what happens internally when persist method is running. I think i already got it in my hibernate log as i shared in the question :DEBUG [80-exec-2 SqlStatementLogger.java: 104] select mySchema.sequence_for_my_entity_PK.nextval from dual

Comment: what may be the reason for the persist() quit after generating the pk without executing the insert statement?? How to know what happens internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is solved. I added these two lines to my **Spring-Core.xml**

```html
<bean id="myDao"  class="com.myPackage.dao.myDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="myAnotherDao" class="com.myPackage.dao.myAnotherDaoImpl" />
```

I never used to specify by dao beans like this before in the spring-core and still it used to work for update ,delete and even for persisting a new entry(Everybody is welcome to clarify this part).But this is the solution that fixed my issue.